# Anthos Config Management, Config sync not installed

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks, google-anthos

I want to install Config sync via Anthos console UI, so a repository is watched and will deliver configuration to my Kubernetes clusters.

While I don't get any error messages, the cluster never leaves the "In progress" status, although nothing is installed. These are EKS clusters.

[Config Management dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W705O.png)

I've also used nomos to check for the installation and it shows the same "NOT INSTALLED" status.

The config management operator was installed following this guide (and checked with a bunch of other guides for consistency):
https://cloud.google.com/anthos-config-management/docs/how-to/installing-kubectl#deploying

The interesting fact here is that, if I deploy a **configmanagement** object with my Git repo configuration using Kubectl, everything works, except that I see this odd configuration in the console, which doesn't help much:

[anthos-console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq2tD.png)

Any pointer to where I can troubleshoot this further will be much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Anthos Config Mgmt and which version of EKS (hopefully 1.18, 1.19 or 1.20)?

Comment: EKS version is 1.19 and Config Management is 1.8.1